# URL changes based on selected item - but page not refreshing

Tags: reactjs

When I navigate from my dashboard, to an account with an id of 1234 (For example), my URL goes from:

`example.com/`

to

`example.com/account/1234`

This works.

But then I want to go to account 5678. So while on my account screen, I try to navigate to:

`example.com/5678`

The URL changes in the browser - but the page doesn't load. I think, because the path, excluding the ID, hasn't changed.

So it went from `example.com/1234` to `example.com/5678`

I'm using `BrowserRouter`

My Route is setup:

```
<Route exact path="/account/:id" component={AccountEditor} />
```

And my link is this:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: `/account/${this.props.accountId}`, state: params}}>{this.props.name}</Link>
```

How can I make it allow a change, when the component remains the same, but the ID changes?

How I use Routes, and this is possibly wrong, because I'm new to this, but it's woriing so far, except for this issue is - I have a mainLayout component. It's devided into two columns. A fixed column on the left which shows info on all pages, and then the main section, which changes based on the selected URL.

```
     <Row>
        <Col md="2">
          <LeftInfoBar />
        </Col>
        <Col md="10">
            <RouteManager />
        </Col>
      </Row>
```

The component, RouteManager, has all the components in it like this:

```
class RouteManager extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                <Route exact path="/accounts" component={Accounts} />
                <Route exact path="/accounts/:id" component={Accounts} />
                ... lots of other components...
            </Switch>
        )
    }

}
export default RouteManager
```

Comment: @can you share your routing config component?

Comment: @VahidAkhtar - Hopefully my edit is what you're asking. The project was initially created with the createReactApp - so not sure where the webpack stuff actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page component will not unmount and then mount because only the URL params are changing and not the route of "/account". What I use in this case is a check if componentDidUpdate that uses the id from props.

This goes inside of your Account page component. You don't have to change any of the routes for this.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.match.params.id !== prevProps.match.params.id) {
    this.setState({ ['someStateProperty']: newValue })
  }
}
```

You'll have to edit the setState to whatever you use, but this will trigger a rerender. If you need to use an api call, you can also use a fetch to get new data inside of that `if` conditional and save the resulting value to state.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @wbd - that worked. I didn't realise the mounting issue. Thanks.